# Como abrir nueva pestaña en una página del navegador que carga un pdf

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf

bueno el título ya dice todo lo que busco, pero os explico un poco la cosa. Tengo una sitio montado en codeigniter, en una de las secciones de la web, a través de la biblioteca TCPDF un enlace lleva al pdf del producto con la configuración que se elige, de este modo el cliente puede descargarlo o imprimirlo y tener ese "resguardo".

Hasta aquí todo bien, lo que ocurre es que en el pdf que se crea hay un par de enlaces que llevan a otros pdfs también creados, al presionar en dicho enlace el pdf se carga en la misma ventana del primer pdf. Se me pide que al presionar el enlace el segundo pdf se abra en otra pestaña del navegador y no en la misma como ocurre ahora.

He buscado por internet información sobre el tema y no he encontrado manera, es más en muchos casos se dice que no es posible.

Si alguien puede ayudarme sería de agradecer. Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: El pdf se crea a partir de html, verdad?

Comment: A través de la biblioteca TCPDF para php, pero bueno sí, con etiquetas html

Comment: Por desgracia, hasta donde yo sé, TCPDF no dispone de ningún método para crear enlaces en el documento PDF que abra el nuevo PDF en una nueva pestaña, ni tan siquiera usando `target="_blank"` en el HTML que genera el PDF.

Comment: Por un lado, el código de TCPDF [no tiene soporte en su código fuente](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/21bb4fdfd505eb67bec603deffc57ce4ff0d408c/tcpdf.php#L4683) para agregar a un enlace algo que no sea una URL o una posición dentro de un documento. Por otro lado, parece que el formato PDF tampoco da soporte a esa funcionalidad porque no está pensado originalmente para ser usado como navegador, aunque en [este hilo del foro de soporte de Adobe](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/853394) explican un truco para crear un EPS que puedes agregar a tu PDF para ejecutar javascript básico.

Comment: Acabo de ver que en el código fuente [hay usos de javascript empotrado](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/21bb4fdfd505eb67bec603deffc57ce4ff0d408c/tcpdf.php#L12434) que podría ayudarte a modificar el código de TCPDF para realizar lo que deseas.

Answer (score 2):

¿Has probado con una etiqueta `a` que utilice un atributo `target` con valor `_blank` ?:

```
<a href="https://../mipdf.pdf" target="_blank">Mi PDF</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta lo siguiente:

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('yoursite.com/LinkToThePDF.pdf');"> link​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ </a>
```

Fuente: [Una pregunta similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742922/tcpdf-open-links-in-new-tab-window) de StackOverflow

Comment: Lo he probado y no me funciona, gracias de todas formas